# WF 4.5 bookmark and persistence in hosted web app

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I developed workflow for an approval system. I used Bookmarks and
Persistence features to persist app state before unloading.

**Workflow**

Send an email to **P1** for approval.

If **P1** approved then next send next approval request to **P2**.

I am using `WorkflowApplication` class to invoke `workflow` from my asp.net application.

I am running my asp.net website on localhost (IIS Express).

*I am not sure how do i handle Application shutdown, restart, scenarios
 for my current workflow.*

My code always hit `app.run` as first thing.

So, suppose, `email to sent P1` for approval and meanwhile i stopped IIS Express/VS.

Now i launch web app again - `app.run` will again so i will lose previous persistence. right?

How i can make sure that workflow is running all the time on hosted application? on IIS server in actual environment? whenever workflow is invoked it should first check whether any previous state persisted? if yes then load that and run from that point?

Any link, help will be appreciated

**My idea:**
On web app restart when it comes to app.run, just check in persistence database and if any previous state persisted, read it out and put some logic to restart from that point.

**But** i really want to know, WF 4.5 does not handle self nicely? how workflowhostservice will help me in this case?

In my following code, i am calling app.run before resuming bookmark 1 and bookmark 2.

**Code:**

```
AutoResetEvent syncEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Guid wfID;
ApprovalWorkflow appFlow = new ApprovalWorkflow 
    { 
        approvalStatus =  "approved" 
    };
WorkflowApplication app = new WorkflowApplication(appFlow);

InstanceStore store = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=WF45GettingStartedTutorial;Integrated Security=True");
InstanceHandle handle = store.CreateInstanceHandle();
InstanceView view = store.Execute(handle, new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
handle.Free();
store.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;
app.InstanceStore = store;


app.PersistableIdle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
{
    return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
};

app.Unloaded = delegate(WorkflowApplicationEventArgs e)
{
    syncEvent.Set();
};

wfID = app.Id;
app.Run();
syncEvent.WaitOne();

// resume bookmark 1
appFlow = new ApprovalWorkflow { approvalStatus = "approved" };
app = new WorkflowApplication(appFlow);
app.InstanceStore = store;

app.PersistableIdle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
{
    return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
};

app.Unloaded = delegate(WorkflowApplicationEventArgs e)
{
    syncEvent.Set();
};

app.Load(wfID);
app.ResumeBookmark("B1", "test1");
syncEvent.WaitOne();

// resume bookmark 2
appFlow = new ApprovalWorkflow { approvalStatus = "approved" };
app = new WorkflowApplication(appFlow);
app.InstanceStore = store;

app.Completed = delegate(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    syncEvent.Set();
};
app.Unloaded = (workflowApplicationEventArgs) =>
{
    syncEvent.Set();
};

app.Load(wfID);
app.ResumeBookmark("B2", "test");
syncEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: WF already stores state when a bookmark is reached or when waiting for an external service and restores a workflow instance using that state. Is this a generic question or did you encounter a problem? Did you check the documentation or any tutorials, eg the [Workflow persistence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489420(v=vs.110).aspx) docs or the [Getting Started tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489454(VS.110).aspx) /

Comment: It is not generic question. My problem is 'whenever i restart from Web App on local machine (IIS Express) .. I have added my code snippet and as per my code app.run invokes always first whenever i restart app. may be my code is not correct and i am missing some imp point here. appreciate if you can figuer out